# Eclipse - How to deny files build/compilation?

Tags: build, compilation, eclipse-plugin

I started using Eclipse with `TFS (Team Foundation Server)` to control file versions, but now I need to control the build/compile access. The idea is similar to the version control system, but it is now related to the project and machines.

Is there a way to control/deny the compilation of specific files with a plugin or not inside `Eclipse`?

Comment: Why would one use a version control system to control what source files are compiled in the build process?

Comment: Hello guys, thank you for your answer.

I believe that the way I asked what I would like to do is incorrect. This is not directly related to the TFS and VisualSVN plugins itself, but I am looking for a solution that allows me to grant/revoke/deny the build/compile access inside eclipse, using a plugin or not. 

I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you want is to manage users to access the project. You can add the users to the Readers group or set permission for a single user.

Check this article for more details:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252477.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I believe that the way I asked what I would like to do is incorrect. This is not directly related to the TFS and VisualSVN plugins itself, but I am looking for a solution that allows me to grant/revoke/deny the build/compile access inside eclipse, using a plugin or not. I'll edit the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about permissions to repositories, VisualSVN Server fully supports path-based authorization and you can manage it through [VisualSVN Server Manager console](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/remote-admin/), [Windows PowerShell](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/) and [Repository Configurator tool](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/delegation/).

Read the article [KB33 | Understanding VisualSVN Server authorization](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/) to learn more about the permissions.

BTW, I second @alroc's comment:

> Why would one use a version control system to control what source
>   files are compiled in the build process?

It seems to me that you are planning to use some awkward approach to control your builds. How does built relate to your version-control system? You should tell the build machine which projects and how to build them. Version control system can only control the authorization part in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I believe that the way I asked what I would like to do is incorrect. This is not directly related to the TFS and VisualSVN plugins itself, but I am looking for a solution that allows me to grant/revoke/deny the build/compile access inside eclipse, using a plugin or not. I'll edit the question to make it clearer